# NSRangeException about NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

please help.thanks a lot.

It happened while I replace characters with a NSAttributedString which contain no character but with a textAttachment.

```
for (int i = (int)imageAndRangeDicArray.count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    NSValue *rangeValue = imageAndRangeDicArray[i][@"range"];
    NSRange range = [rangeValue rangeValue];

    DLog(@"%@",string);
    DLog(@"location:%lu,length:%lu",(unsigned long)range.location,(unsigned long)range.length);

    [emtionString replaceCharactersInRange:range withAttributedString:imageAndRangeDicArray[i][@"image"]];
}
```

the string is已首发[亲亲]

the range is location:3,length:4

it is not out of range.

It works fine at string like this

错了，是楚商杂志[呲牙][呲牙]

location:8,length:4

Comment: what do you mean that you are replacing with an attributed string which contain no characters?  What is the text attachment?

Comment: sorry. I am not a native english speaker.It means the NSAttributedString init with a textAttachment but not string.like this                NSAttributedString *imageStr = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

Comment: For a string of "已首发[亲亲]" with a location of 3 & a length of 4, that range is definitely longer than the string.  The character at location 3 is "[" and the length of that string is 6.

Comment: [亲亲]'s length is four.So 已首发[亲亲]'s length is 7.

Comment: thanks. I figure it out.It is not the range problem.It is some silly mistake.